# How to push a manifest.yml programmatically in cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have multiple applications listed in my manifest.yml. I want to push all of them to a cf space I created programmatically. Is there any easy way to do that like pushing the manifest directly like cf push does?

Comment: What did you use to create the space programatically? Are you asking if you can push all the apps programitically without using the "cf" CLI?

Comment: ReactorCloudFoundryClient. Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No easy way based on:

https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/816799/stories/106155274 (no existing manifest support)

More on

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues/216

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues/432

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about pushing apps to CF programmatically. There are many ways to push apps to Cloud Foundry.

- If you are using IDE and you don't want to write manifest.yml file to push. Then you can install cloud foundry plugins in IDE. After installing plugins, you have to create server for cloud foundry and need to specify endpoint, credentials, orgs and spaces.
- You have multiple apps required to push then just add apps in CF configurations in IDE.
- Once you mentioned like apps, domain, memory, buildpacks, orgs and spaces, it will automatically create manifest.yml file for you. You can click push button to push apps to Cloud Foundry.
- If you are not using IDE, then you have create manifest.yml file manually. Please have a look at this link to understand clearly to push multiple apps to cloud foundry. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#multi-apps